# Aggregate info from one DataFrame and join it to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, join, aggregate

I have two pandas DataFrames: one is transaction history between companies (their IDs), week of transaction and sum of the transaction. So, each company in 'sell' column make transactions to companies from different regions ('buy' column).

Another is specification table, contained company IDs and region. I need to generate feature for ML model - mean payment from **each company to each region** and to join it to specification dataframe.

I can't just join 'region' column to transaction table because not all companies from specification table are in 'sell' or in 'buy' column. Companies from specification table are **either** in 'sell' **or** in 'buy' column.

First DataFrame (transactions):
[image]

Second DataFrame (specification):
[image]

I need DataFrame like this:
[image]

I think to move towards groupby by 'sell Id' but have no ideas what to do next.

Please help

Comment: You are probably looking for pivot

Comment: @Artic_kh, please provide data not as image but in an executable form - you will get more answers that way! Look into joining the two dataframes with pandas `join` or `merge` and then using pandas `pivot` or `pivot_table` to construct the summary,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for.

```
# Generate sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([['AAA','CCC',25,14],['AAA','CCC',50,18],['AAA','DDD',10,20],['AAA','DDD',20,25]])
    df.columns = ['sell','buy','sum','week']

#Generate second table
spec = pd.DataFrame([['CCC',21],['DDD',22]])
spec.columns = ['companyID','region']

# Merge the two dataframes
df = df.merge(spec, left_on='buy',right_on='companyID')

# Group by whatever columns you need, and take the mean
df = df.groupby(['sell','region'])['sum'].mean().reset_index()

# Pivot your data
df.pivot(index='sell', columns='region', values='sum')
```

## Output

```
region    21    22
sell
AAA     37.5  15.0
```

Comment: @jezrael It's a Snook caught off the pier in Dania Beach Florida